# Cross-thread operation not valid using timer and 2 buttons

Tags: c#, exception, invoke

i got this problem...

What would be a good solution for this?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        button1.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void timer_is_working(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Thanks!
Kind regards
Daniel Ruescher

Comment: Inside of `timer_is_working`, you can only enable `button1` in the user interface thread. There is a dedicated thread for the UI most likely (although not sure what kind of application you are working on), so you will need to do something like: `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { button1.Enabled = true; });` inside of `timer_is_working`. BTW, your question is poorly written and people will down-vote it; to be safe if I were you I would revise the question and change the wording around to help people know where your  problem actually is. You may want to consider adding more code to be more descriptive.

Comment: Please add more text, info and research. Show us what you've done. We are here to help you learn, not free software support.

Answer (score 10):

So you did not make it clear, but based on the `ElapsedEventArgs` type it seems that `timer_is_working` is the `Elapsed` event of a `System.Timers.Timer` instance.

> Be aware that the .NET Framework Class Library includes four classes
>      named Timer, each of which offers different functionality:
>
> - System.Timers.Timer: fires an event at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service
>     component in a multithreaded environment.
> - System.Threading.Timer: executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is
>     defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like
>     the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a
>     server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment.
> - System.Windows.Forms.Timer: a Windows Forms component that fires an event at regular intervals. The component is designed for use in a single-threaded environment.
> - System.Web.UI.Timer: an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.

If this is a Windows.Forms app, use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead (you find it in Toolbox/Components). Its `Tick` event is raised in the UI thread so can access your controls from there.

If you have a special reason to use the `System.Timers.Timer` (eg. precision), you must wrap your access into an `Invoke` call:

```
Invoke(new Action(() => { button1.Enabled = true; }));
```

Comment: I was using System.Timers.Timer from an example code in a WPF app but was trying to use that on a WinForms app. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Invoke` to update UI by using UI thread.

Try this example

```
private void timer_is_working(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteSecure(() => aTimer.Enabled = false);        
    ExecuteSecure(() => button1.Enabled = true);
}

private void ExecuteSecure(Action action)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            action();
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```