# System.Timers.Timer and DataBinding

Tags: vb.net

If I have a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and I have a property in that class that is bound to a label on a form, how do I avoid a Cross-threaded exception if I set the property value from a System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed event handler?

The following code demonstrates the exception.

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Form1

    Private thisClass As New aClass
    Private WithEvents tmr As New System.Timers.Timer()
    Private lbl As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        'create the label and add it to the form
        lbl = New Label
        lbl.Text = "some text"
        Me.Controls.Add(lbl)

        'set the data binding and start a timer
        lbl.DataBindings.Add("Text", thisClass, "X")
        tmr.Interval = 1000
        AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf tmr_Elapsed
        tmr.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        'change the property value when the timer elapses
        thisClass.X = Guid.NewGuid.ToString

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class aClass
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _x As String = ""
    Public Property X As String
        Get
            Return _x
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _x = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("X"))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? If you do have one, use `Me.Invoke(New Action(Sub() thisClass.X = Guid.NewGuid.ToString()))`. If not, just switch to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` whose `Tick` event runs on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: Duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid using timer and 2 buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353118/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-using-timer-and-2-buttons).

Comment: @41686d6564 - Do I have to use a System Timer, no, but a Forms timer in this case would be a waste of the UI time slice. Also, I don't see how this question is a duplicate. In your duplicate post, it's obvious that an Invoke is need. With data binding, there is no opportunity to invoke

Comment: What causes the exception is that the `aClass.X` property is changed _on a worker thread_ and since that property is bound to a UI control, the control's property is also being accessed from the worker thread. By invoking, you ensure that `X` is changed on the UI thread, causing the control's property to also be accessed (and changed) from the UI thread. Did you try the code in my first comment?

Comment: I understand why the exception occurs, and no I did not try your code. I think you are missing the fact that I am data bound. To use your code, I would need to explicitly handle the change event.  With data binding, there is no event I can handle.

Comment: _"No I did not"_ Then, please do. Replace the `thisClass.X = Guid.NewGuid.ToString` line with the code in my first comment and let me if it doesn't work (spoiler alert: it _will_ work). I'm well aware that you're using data binding and I explained above why the exception is thrown and how using `Invoke()` will prevent that. Please let me know if you have any more questions. I'll be happy to help :)

Comment: Your answer is in the first comment.

Comment: *"a Forms timer in this case would be a waste of the UI time slice"*. Obviously it wouldn't if the only thing you need to do in the event handler is going to affect the UI. Any action that affects the UI must be performed on the UI thread. Anything that must be performed on the UI thread is not a waste of the UI thread's time.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach could be to use an asynchronous method to keep updating code on same thread.

```
Public Class MyForm
  Private _viewmodel As MyViewModel 
  Private _intervalTask As Task
  Private _canContinueIntervalRunning As Boolean

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    _viewmodel = New MyViewModel()

    CreateLabel() ' Create label and bind to viewmodel property
    
    ' Start interval without blocking this code execution
    ' Later we can use this saved task to make sure that task is complete
    _canContinueIntervalRunning = True
    _intervalTask = StartInterval()
  End Sub

  Private Async Function StartInterval() As Task
    While _canContinueIntervalRunning
      Await Task.Delay(1000)
      _viewmodel.X = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    End While
  End Function

  Private Async Sub FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyForm.FormClosing
    ' Set "flag" to false and wait for task to complete
    _canContinueIntervalRunning = False
    Await _intervalTask
  End Sub
End Class
```

With `Await Task.Delay(1000)` next line will be executed on same thread, which allows to update form controls without extra effort.

This is simple approach with boolean flag, another way of doing it would be to use cancellation token which you can pass to `Task.Delay` - then form don't need to wait for extra second, but can cancel `Delay` straight away.